# How to Download Images On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for downloading images but when I click the download button it will start the download process but the download doesn't complete and no file is received but a type error is found.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function prepHref(linkElement) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('fullsized_image_holder');
    var myImage = myDiv.children[0];
    linkElement.href = myImage.src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fullsized_image_holder">
```

```
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="prepHref(this)" download>Click here to download image</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the link to the image actually returns a 404 - the image doesn't exist on the server?

Comment: Is the file exists on the download link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery File Download Plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) ,refenced by [Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834261/8090014)

Example

```
prepHref(image){
    $.fileDownload('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/xDskNs1CNhU/W_uw44XJ70I/AAAAAAAAGTg/3trA_Gh3GsojvuhQ1eljASYla7Y5SulGQCLcBGAs/s200/Fadex.jpg')
       .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
       .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below one.

```
<div id="div-id"><img src="yourImage.jpg" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="this.href = $('#div-id img:first').attr('src');" download>Clickdownload image</a>
```

div-id is the div which is holding the image.

Comment: File Download but  File Not Found This Error
and if i put <ima src="link of my post images  " style="margin-top: 0px;">
then click  then it open in new tab

Comment: Try putting the full path of the image.